# In the Batman TV series, was there an "up" mode for the Bat Pole?

Tags: dc, batman, batman-1966

My memory insists I watched Batman and Robin step on a disk at the base of the pole, and some mechanism raises the disk upwards, accompanied by smoke or steam.

But [here](https://youtu.be/sTlQtBQELwE?t=36s) it's obvious there's a cushion at the base.  So I might be wrong.

Comment: "Bat-Pole", that's beautiful.

Comment: I loved this version of Batman,  may they never make it again. Same Bat-Time, Same Bat channel.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## Yes.

There was an original series episode where the Joker is in Wayne Manor and Batman and Robin need to go from the cave back up the [Batpoles](http://batman60stv.wikia.com/wiki/Batpoles). They used a compressed steam lift under the pads to push them back up.

[image: Batpole lift buttons]
[image: View of the lift buttons that shows a “Negate Costume Change” button behind Robin.]
[image: Batman and Robin using the Batpole lifts.]

Comment: Thanks!  Follow-up question: when going up, did their clothes change to civies (usually rich-dude casual, sweater & tie)?

Comment: @CedricSilvester In this case, no. It's hard to see in the bottom picture but there's a switch that controls that. [You can see it clearly in this image though](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/batman60stv/images/a/a5/Compressed_steam_lift.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20171213164706)